# Change modifier visibility for multiple objects at once

Tags: modifiers, objects, scene, visibility

I want to turn modifier visibility on/off for all objects in my scene at once.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is to select all objects, then go to *Modifiers*, click on visibility button and then <kbd>Right Click</kbd>  on that button.

There will be a menu that will give you option to *Copy to Selected*. That will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>  to visibility button in Blender 2.80